# Where is this Rails file stored? db/development.sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, configuration

I'm trying to find the sqlite database file that rails creates.

Sorry if this is a dumb question but which folder is this file stored in?

I've looked in all of the folders in my Rails project and can't find it.

My `database.yml`:

```
   development:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/development.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's in RAILS_ROOT/db/development.sqlite3

Comment: what if u do a capistrano deploy?

Answer (score 2):

You can find your database file after you have give "scaffold" command at following directory
If you are in your project folder then
then go to "DB" folder
then you can see "development.sqlite3" file this is the sqlite database file

Answer (score 1):

FWIW the file might not exist if you haven't done rake db:create yet.

Answer (score -1):

`sqlite://db/development.sqlite3`

Comment: What is this telling us? It looks like a URL, but pasting it into my browser (Firefox) does't yield anything useful – just a Google search that brings me back here :-). Is it just shorthand for the first answer?

Comment: This is not correct.